# When to bind a service and when not to bind a service

Tags: android, service

I have been paging through the Android documentation and I was curious. When would you bind a service as opposed to not binding the service? What advantages/limitations does it provide?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

> When would you bind a service as opposed to not binding the service?

A full answer to that requires a few pages in (::ahem::) a book. :-)

Binding to a service presents challenges when it comes to deal with configuration changes, such as screen rotations. Hence, all else being equal, using the command pattern (`startService()`) beats using the binding pattern (`bindService()`).

You have to use the command pattern if you want your service to run without any activity around to be bound to it. So, a music player, a large-file downloader, or a cron job set up with `AlarmManager` would all tend to use the command pattern.

Binding gives you access to a richer API, including support for data types that will not work with the command pattern (which is limited to things you can stick in a `Bundle`).

Comment: Awesome, this is exactly what I needed, thank you so much! I have been looking into buying one of your books. Which one would work best if I have already been through a few Android books and have written a few applications of my own?

Comment: @Andrew Guenther: I don't want to turn this into a commercial. Suffice it to say, the Warescription gives you all the books (digital), for about what you would pay for one in print.

Comment: But i don't get it.. since the services run in the main thread, there is no much purpose for them when you have activities involved. I mean.. isn't the whole purpose of the service to be just a "faceless" activity that can keep on running while the user plays with another thing? So you basically say the binding process between activities and services is a one time only event and once the activity has gone there is no way for another activity instance to rebind to the service.. In which kind of cases SHOULD I bind them then? couldn't I just fire threads from the activity in those cases?